# for loop in c# for IDs of controls to read text of textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
.
.
.
<asp:TextBox ID="PFtxtname100" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I need to create for loop to read all data of txt and save all in string array variable!

```
       //string[] arr = new string[100];
        //   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         //  { 
               //arr[i] = (i+1).ToString();
               //i+=1; 
               //TextBox mytext = new TextBox();
               //mytext.ID = "PFtxtname" + i;
               //TextBox txtbox = Page.FindControl("PFtxtname"+i) as TextBox;


               //i += 1; 
               //arr[i] = txtbox.Text;
          //}
```

Comment: So what have you tried, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: use for loop and FindControl

Comment: Have you tried... uncommenting your code?  Does it fail in some way?

Comment: I can't read any data ! is must i use TextBox txtbox = Page.FindControl("PFtxtname"+i) as TextBox;

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please provide any detail and data that can help us help you.  Also, do appropriate research prior to posting.  There are MANY different ways to do this, and it can differ between ASP.NET frameworks (forms/mvc/razor/etc); many of which have questions already asked and answered on stackoverflow.

In any case this should at least get you started. LINQ is your friend! (may need to add using)

```cs
    var listOfText = new List<string>();
    foreach (var textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        listOfText.Add(textbox.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
//Member variable
var textBox = new TextBox();

public void CreateTextBox(int length)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
            textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.ID = "PFtxtname" + "_" + index;
            textBox.CssClass = "yourCSSClass";
            textBox.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
            this.Controls.Add(textBox);
     }
}
```

get the textbox values bt  calling getTextBoxValues method

```
public string[] getTextBoxValues(int length)
{
        string[] arr = new string[length];
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
            TextBox txtbox = Page.FindControl("PFtxtname_"+ index) as TextBox;
            arr[nRowIndex] = txtbox.value;
        }
        return arr;
}
```